# Emgu CV SURF get matched points coordinates

Tags: c#, image, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I'm using Emgu CV's SURF feauture to recognize similar objects in images.

The image is drawn right, showing all the key points found, in both images, the *similar* points (**which is what I want**) and a rectangle (usually rectangle, sometimes just a line) that covers the similar points.

The problem is that the *similar points* are seen in the image, but they are not saved in the format I want, in fact, they're stored in a **VectorOfKeyPoint** object, which just stores a pointer, and other memory data, where the points are stored in memory (that's what I think). Meaning, I can't get the *similar points* in pairs like:

**((img1X, img1Y), (img2X, img2Y))**

This would be what I'm looking for, so that I can use the points later one.
Right now, I can just see the points in the resulted image, but I can't get
them in pairs.

The code that I'm using is the example from Emgu CV.

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Copyright (C) 2004-2016 by EMGU Corporation. All rights reserved.       
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Features2D;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
#if !__IOS__
using Emgu.CV.Cuda;
#endif
using Emgu.CV.XFeatures2D;

namespace FirstEmgu
{

    public static class DrawMatches
    {
  // --------------------------------
  // ORIGINAL FUNCTION FROM EXAMPLE
  // --------------------------------
        private static void FindMatch(Mat modelImage, Mat observedImage, out long matchTime, out VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints, out VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints, VectorOfVectorOfDMatch matches, out Mat mask, out Mat homography)
        {
            int k = 2;
            double uniquenessThreshold = 0.8;
            double hessianThresh = 300;

            Stopwatch watch;
            homography = null;

            modelKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();
            observedKeyPoints = new VectorOfKeyPoint();

#if !__IOS__
            if (CudaInvoke.HasCuda)
            {
                CudaSURF surfCuda = new CudaSURF((float)hessianThresh);
                using (GpuMat gpuModelImage = new GpuMat(modelImage))
                //extract features from the object image
                using (GpuMat gpuModelKeyPoints = surfCuda.DetectKeyPointsRaw(gpuModelImage, null))
                using (GpuMat gpuModelDescriptors = surfCuda.ComputeDescriptorsRaw(gpuModelImage, null, gpuModelKeyPoints))
                using (CudaBFMatcher matcher = new CudaBFMatcher(DistanceType.L2))
                {
                    surfCuda.DownloadKeypoints(gpuModelKeyPoints, modelKeyPoints);
                    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                    // extract features from the observed image
                    using (GpuMat gpuObservedImage = new GpuMat(observedImage))
                    using (GpuMat gpuObservedKeyPoints = surfCuda.DetectKeyPointsRaw(gpuObservedImage, null))
                    using (GpuMat gpuObservedDescriptors = surfCuda.ComputeDescriptorsRaw(gpuObservedImage, null, gpuObservedKeyPoints))
                    //using (GpuMat tmp = new GpuMat())
                    //using (Stream stream = new Stream())
                    {
                        matcher.KnnMatch(gpuObservedDescriptors, gpuModelDescriptors, matches, k);

                        surfCuda.DownloadKeypoints(gpuObservedKeyPoints, observedKeyPoints);

                        mask = new Mat(matches.Size, 1, DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
                        mask.SetTo(new MCvScalar(255));
                        Features2DToolbox.VoteForUniqueness(matches, uniquenessThreshold, mask);

                        int nonZeroCount = CvInvoke.CountNonZero(mask);
                        if (nonZeroCount >= 4)
                        {
                            nonZeroCount = Features2DToolbox.VoteForSizeAndOrientation(modelKeyPoints, observedKeyPoints,
                               matches, mask, 1.5, 20);
                            if (nonZeroCount >= 4)
                                homography = Features2DToolbox.GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures(modelKeyPoints,
                                   observedKeyPoints, matches, mask, 2);
                        }
                    }
                    watch.Stop();
                }
            }
            else
#endif
            {
                using (UMat uModelImage = modelImage.ToUMat(AccessType.Read))
                using (UMat uObservedImage = observedImage.ToUMat(AccessType.Read))
                {
                    SURF surfCPU = new SURF(hessianThresh);
                    //extract features from the object image
                    UMat modelDescriptors = new UMat();
                    surfCPU.DetectAndCompute(uModelImage, null, modelKeyPoints, modelDescriptors, false);

                    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                    // extract features from the observed image
                    UMat observedDescriptors = new UMat();
                    surfCPU.DetectAndCompute(uObservedImage, null, observedKeyPoints, observedDescriptors, false);
                    BFMatcher matcher = new BFMatcher(DistanceType.L2);
                    matcher.Add(modelDescriptors);

                    matcher.KnnMatch(observedDescriptors, matches, k, null);
                    mask = new Mat(matches.Size, 1, DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
                    mask.SetTo(new MCvScalar(255));
                    Features2DToolbox.VoteForUniqueness(matches, uniquenessThreshold, mask);

                    int nonZeroCount = CvInvoke.CountNonZero(mask);
                    if (nonZeroCount >= 4)
                    {
                        nonZeroCount = Features2DToolbox.VoteForSizeAndOrientation(modelKeyPoints, observedKeyPoints,
                           matches, mask, 1.5, 20);
                        if (nonZeroCount >= 4)
                            homography = Features2DToolbox.GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures(modelKeyPoints,
                               observedKeyPoints, matches, mask, 2);
                    }

                    watch.Stop();
                }
            }
            matchTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
        // --------------------------------
        // ORIGINAL FUNCTION FROM EXAMPLE
        // --------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Draw the model image and observed image, the matched features and homography projection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="modelImage">The model image</param>
        /// <param name="observedImage">The observed image</param>
        /// <param name="matchTime">The output total time for computing the homography matrix.</param>
        /// <returns>The model image and observed image, the matched features and homography projection.</returns>
        public static Mat Draw(Mat modelImage, Mat observedImage, out long matchTime)
        {
            Mat homography;
            VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints;
            VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints;
            using (VectorOfVectorOfDMatch matches = new VectorOfVectorOfDMatch())
            {
                Mat mask;
                FindMatch(modelImage, observedImage, out matchTime, out modelKeyPoints, out observedKeyPoints, matches,
                   out mask, out homography);

                //Draw the matched keypoints
                Mat result = new Mat();
                Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches(modelImage, modelKeyPoints, observedImage, observedKeyPoints,
                   matches, result, new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), mask);

                #region draw the projected region on the image

                if (homography != null)
                {
                    //draw a rectangle along the projected model
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, modelImage.Size);
                    PointF[] pts = new PointF[]
               {
                  new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Bottom),
                  new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Bottom),
                  new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Top),
                  new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Top)
               };
                    pts = CvInvoke.PerspectiveTransform(pts, homography);

                    Point[] points = Array.ConvertAll<PointF, Point>(pts, Point.Round);
                    using (VectorOfPoint vp = new VectorOfPoint(points))
                    {
                        CvInvoke.Polylines(result, vp, true, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 5);
                    }

                }

                #endregion

                return result;

            }
        }

        // ----------------------------------
        // WRITTEN BY MYSELF
        // ----------------------------------
        // Returns 4 points (usually rectangle) of similar points
        // but can't be used, since sometimes this is a line (negative 
        // points)
        public static Point[] FindPoints(Mat modelImage, Mat observedImage, out long matchTime)
        {
            Mat homography;
            VectorOfKeyPoint modelKeyPoints;
            VectorOfKeyPoint observedKeyPoints;
            using (VectorOfVectorOfDMatch matches = new VectorOfVectorOfDMatch())
            {
                Mat mask;
                FindMatch(modelImage, observedImage, out matchTime, out modelKeyPoints, out observedKeyPoints, matches,
                   out mask, out homography);

                //Draw the matched keypoints
                Mat result = new Mat();
                Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches(modelImage, modelKeyPoints, observedImage, observedKeyPoints,
                   matches, result, new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), mask);

                Point[] points = null;
                if (homography != null)
                {
                    //draw a rectangle along the projected model
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, modelImage.Size);
                    PointF[] pts = new PointF[]
               {
                  new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Bottom),
                  new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Bottom),
                  new PointF(rect.Right, rect.Top),
                  new PointF(rect.Left, rect.Top)
               };
                    pts = CvInvoke.PerspectiveTransform(pts, homography);

                    points = Array.ConvertAll<PointF, Point>(pts, Point.Round);

                }

                return points;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I've managed to get some points out of the matches objects like this:

```
Features2DToolbox.DrawMatches(modelImage, modelKeyPoints, observedImage, observedKeyPoints,
                   matches, result, new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), mask);

                for (int i = 0; i < matches.Size; i++)
                {
                    var a = matches[i].ToArray();
                    foreach (var e in a)
                    {
                        Point p = new Point(e.TrainIdx, e.QueryIdx);
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Point: {0}", p));
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
                }
```

I think this should get me the points. I managed to get it working in python, and the code is not very different. Problem is that there are too many points that are returned. In fact, this returns me all the points on Y.

**Example**

(45, 1), (67, 1)

(656, 2), (77, 2)

...

It doesn't get me the points I want, even though I might be close. Any suggestions are appreciated.

**EDIT 2**
This question: [Find interest point in surf Detector Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637916/find-interest-point-in-surf-detector-algorithm) is something very similar to what I need. There is only one answer, but it doesn't tell how to get the matched points coordinates. That's what I need, if there is an object in both images, get the coordinates of the objects points, from both images.

Answer (score 5):

The coordinates is not made of TrainIdx and QueryIdx, those are indices of the KeyPoints. This will give the pixel coordinates that match between the model and observed image.

```
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Size; i++)
{
    var arrayOfMatches = matches[i].ToArray();
    if (mask.GetData(i)[0] == 0) continue;
    foreach (var match in arrayOfMatches)
    {
        var matchingModelKeyPoint = modelKeyPoints[match.TrainIdx];
        var matchingObservedKeyPoint = observedKeyPoints[match.QueryIdx];
        Console.WriteLine("Model coordinate '" + matchingModelKeyPoint.Point + "' matches observed coordinate '" + matchingObservedKeyPoint.Point + "'.");
    }
}
```

The number of items in arrayOfMatches equals the value of K. It is my understanding that the match with the lowest distance is the best.

Comment: A small fix for the answer of Mike de Klerk var maskData = mask.GetData(0, i); if (maskData[0] == 0) continue;

Answer (score 2):

In the `FindMatch` function, each pair of point is validated by the function `VoteForUniqueness`. The result of this validation is stored in `mask`.

So all you have to do is check if the match is validated or not :

```
for (int i = 0; i < matches.Size; i++)
{
    var a = matches[i].ToArray();
    if (mask.GetData(i)[0] == 0)
        continue;
    foreach (var e in a)
    {
        Point p = new Point(e.TrainIdx, e.QueryIdx);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Point: {0}", p));
    }
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
}
```